# Where is it safe to connect drain pipe of RO filtration system?

Tags: plumbing, water, kitchens

I'm installing [iSpring RCC7AK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005LJ8EXU) filtration system in a rental apartment so I'd love to minimize impact on existing equipment.

I'm considering 4 locations to connect:

1. Drill a hole in the cap. I can't use saddle so I guess I'd have to glue the pipe;
2. Drill a hole on top of the wide tube;
3. Drill a hole on the side. Too big to use included saddle;
4. It's drain tube from washing machine.

Currently I'm tempted to go with option (1) because I can easily replace the cap. I like location (4) as well but I wonder if there is a risk contamination of clean water in RO tank when washing machine is draining water.

Where should I connect it? Is there better option that I haven't mention?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do the instructions tell you? Are there any warnings about cross contamination?
If not, I would tap into the top of the stub at #2 using the saddle. I don't like having a stub like that because it tends to collect debris but the clean discharge from the RO drain will actually help clear it.
A bigger issue is that S trap! I don't know your location but that's not code compliant anywhere I know of in the US.

Comment: Yes, interesting that you mentioned S-trap because I just watched video of Florida man who said exactly that :) I'm temporary in the UK and the trap looks suspect to me too.

Comment: As per cross contamination iSpring instruction is fairly brief. Perhaps I should email them.

Comment: If their instructions tell you to tap into an under-sink drain, I'm sure it's fine on top of #2.